# Can using inheritance let me enforce stronger typedefs?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, strong-typedef

I have a type `RenderName` that's used to describe an allocation on the GPU.  Passing one that describes a "shader" into a function expecting a "texture" would cause a lot of problems though, so I want to use C++'s type system to help enforce that this doesn't occur, while still allowing all `RenderName`s to be treated as the same type when it's useful.

Will using inheritance like I have with `TextureName` and such, result in this kind of behavior, without forcing the compiler to generate less efficient code?

```
class RenderName {
public:
    // ctor and dtor do a lot of intense work, similar to a shared pointer
    RenderName();
    RenderName(RenderName && other);
    RenderName(const RenderName & other);
    RenderName & operator=(RenderName && other);
    RenderName & operator=(const RenderName & other);
    ~RenderName();

    uint32 name() const;
    
protected:
    RenderName(uint32 engine, uint32 type); 

    uint32 m_guts;
};


// "typedefs"
class TextureName : public RenderName {};
class BufferName : public RenderName {};
class ShaderName : public RenderName {};

static_assert(sizeof(TextureName) == sizeof(RenderName), "These subtypes should keep the same size");
```

I wrote some code to help illustrate the behavior I'm chasing.  (I almost never get to use inheritance, so I don't have the best handle on it.)

```
BufferName allocateBuffer() { ... }
void bindShader(ShaderName name) { ... }
void debugName(RenderName name) { ... }

int main() {
    std::vector<RenderName> array;
    TextureName name;
    RenderName base;

    // I'd want these to all *fail* compilation
    name = base;
    name = allocateBuffer(); 
    bindShader(name); 

    // BUT... I'd want these to work okay?
    base = name;
    debugName(name);
    array.push_back(name);  
}
```

Comment: Nothing wrong there. I'm not answering properly as I don't know what to add to that.

Comment: See also [Boost Strong Typdef](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/serialization/doc/strong_typedef.html)

Comment: It isn't quite clear *why* you want `bindShader(base);` to work okay. Your `base` is really a texture, no?

Comment: polymorphism needs references or pointers. No reference or pointers -> no polymorphism.

Comment: @n.m. - thank you for catching that, I actually don't want that behavior, I miswrote that, it should be fixed now

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number no polymorphism seems to be expected here. There is no virtual anything. On the contrary, object slicing is expected.

Comment: I can't find fault in the small example you posted. Seems no different than defining traits as sub-types of `std::true_type` and `std::false_type`. You want strong typing, you get strong typing. Your objects are small and cheap to slice, so nothing terrible there. At worst I only see you getting annoying by compiler warnings about slicing.